# Javascript: method returns undefined when value is not undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do

```
if (program.url) {
        checkJson = checkUrl(program.url, program.checks);
        console.log('checkJson:', checkJson);
    }
```

and

```
var checkUrl = function (url, checksfile) {
    var checks = loadChecks(checksfile).sort();
    rest.get(program.url).on('complete', function(data) {
        var out = {};
        $ = cheerioUrlData(data);
        for (var ii in checks) {
            var present = $(checks[ii]).length > 0;
            out[checks[ii]] = present;
        }
        console.log(out); // <<-- This console
        return out;
    });
};
```

The console looks like

```
{ '.about': true,
  '.blank': true,
  '.faq': true,
  '.footer': true,
  '.heading': true,
  '.logo': true,
  '.navigation': true,
  '.order': true,
  '.pitch': true,
  '.section1': true,
  '.section2': true,
  '.social': true,
  '.subheading': true,
  '.thermometer': true,
  '.video': true,
  h1: true }
```

but `console.log('checkJson:', checkJson);`  prints

```
checkJson: undefined
```

What is incorrect here?

Comment: It's asynchronous ?

Comment: `checkUrl` has no return value...why would you expect the return value to be anything other than `undefined`?

Comment: It returns **immediately**.  It didn't have time to get the information yet.  When it does, it calls the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return out;` returns from your "complete" callback and not from `checkUrl`.  `checkUrl` returns immediately (before the `rest.get` returns).  You need to use a callback to get the value you are looking for:

```
if (program.url) {
       checkUrl(program.url, program.checks, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
       } );
}
```

and

```
var checkUrl = function (url, checksfile, callback) {
    var checks = loadChecks(checksfile).sort();
    rest.get(program.url).on('complete', function(data) {
        var out = {};
        $ = cheerioUrlData(data);
        for (var ii in checks) {
            var present = $(checks[ii]).length > 0;
            out[checks[ii]] = present;
        }
        console.log(out); // <<-- This console
        callback(out);
    });
};
```

Comment: I never knew about this, thanks a ton! where can I learn more about this?

Comment: @daydreamer Never knew about what? How `return` statements work? Or how to call functions?